# php using include

Tags: php, include

I have the following problem,

I'm trying to make my website more clear for myself so i'm using this for example in my index.php:

```
<body>
    <?php include 'layout/menu.php' ?>
    <?php include 'includes/Hoofdmenu.php' ?>
</body>
```

But now i'd like it so that if someone clicks for example 'contact' as menu option that it changes the include instead of the whole page.

I appreciate any help to push me in the right direction,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @rid thanks, ill save my second question for another time then. Let's not get people confused.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
if ( $menuOption == 'contact' )
{
    <?php include 'includes/contact.php' ?>
}
```

should do it. In order to prevent, that contact.php gets called directly from the url, configure your apache accordingly in `.htaccess` for the includes directory:

```
   <Directory "....../includes">
    Order deny,Allow
    Deny from all
   </Directory>
```

Comment: And how do I set the $menuOption? Sorry for the silly question but im new with php and JS.

Comment: from the link on the menu with some query option like `...&menu=contact...` and further `$menuOption = $_REQUEST['menu'];`